# Proof of boost generator $K_0$ commute with $S$-matix in Weinberg QFT 1

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, inertial-frames, s-matrix-theory

In Weinberg QFT Vol.1, Weinberg defines a boost operator K when there exists an interaction $V$ as
$$\textbf{K}=\textbf{K}_0+\textbf{W}, \tag{3.3.20}$$
where $\textbf{W}$ is expected as a correction to $\textbf{K}_0$ when $H=H_0+V$.

One can get the commutation relation(Weinberg QFT Vol.1 Page 120 (3.3.22)),
$$[\textbf{K}_0,U(\tau,\tau_0)]=-\textbf{W}(\tau)U(\tau,\tau_0)+U(\tau,\tau_0)\textbf{W}(\tau_0),
\tag{3.3.22} $$
where
$$\textbf{W}(t)\equiv \exp(iH_0t)\textbf{W}\exp(-iH_0t),\tag{3.3.23}$$
$$U(t,t_0)=\exp(iH_0t)\exp(-iH(t-t_0))\exp(-iH_0t_0)~;\tag{3.2.6}$$
then he argues that

> If the matrix elements of **W** between $H_0$-eigenstates are sufficiently smooth functions of energy, then matrix elements of **W**(t) between smooth superpositions of energy eigenstates vanish for $t \rightarrow \pm \infty $,so Eq. (3.3.22) gives in
> $$0=[\textbf{K}_0,U(\infty,-\infty)]=[\textbf{K}_0,S].\tag{3.3.24}$$

I'm quite confused about how this arugment makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

From equation (3.3.21), we see that there would be singularities in the matrix elements of $\mathbf{W}$

$$[\mathbf{K}_0, V] = - [\mathbf{W}, H]\tag{3.3.21}$$

The elements of $\mathbf{W}$,

$$\left(\Psi_{\beta}, [\mathbf{W}, H]\Psi_{\alpha}\right) = (E_{\alpha}-E_{\beta})\left(\Psi_{\beta}, \mathbf{W}\Psi_{\alpha}\right) = -\left(\Psi_{\beta}, [\mathbf{K}_0, H]\Psi_{\alpha}\right)$$

As Weinberg says, there would be singularities $\left(E_{\beta}-E_{\alpha}\right)^{-1}$.
The additional smoothness condition on $\mathbf{W}$ is to solve this problem, and this could be achieve by simulating the cessation of interaction and adiabatically decreases in the interaction strength as $t\rightarrow\pm\infty$.

As Weinberg puts, this smoothness condition is a natural one.